# Extract xml tags from xml String

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am working in an web application. In my project I am using xml for dynamic UI generations. I have an xml which i want to transform that into xsl so that i can use that for UI.
My question is,

I have an xml string,How can i do the following?

from these xml string,

```
<editor_tab label="Editor">
        <attributes>
            <attribute sequenceNo="12" dataType="string" controltype="Editor"
                name="additional_info" UILabel="Notes" mandatory="N" default="NA"
                updatable="Y" viewable="Y" attribute_id="END12" />
        </attributes>
    </editor_tab>
    <document_tab label="Document">
        <attributes>
            <attributePair displayName="Entity Attributes" name="FileSet1"
                class="entityAttr">
                <attribute sequenceNo="1" dataType="string" controltype="TD"
                    name="Filename" UILabel="" attribute_id="END407" />
                <attribute sequenceNo="2" dataType="string" controltype="Hidden"
                    name="FileBytestream" UILabel="" attribute_id="END408" />
                <attribute sequenceNo="3" dataType="string" controltype="Hidden"
                    name="AllowedType" UILabel="" attribute_id="END409" />
                <attribute sequenceNo="4" dataType="string" controltype="Hidden"
                    name="AllowedMaxSize" UILabel="" attribute_id="END410" />
            </attributePair>
```

i have to extract as separate xml like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><editor_tab label="Editor">
        <attributes>
            <attribute sequenceNo="12" dataType="string" controltype="Editor"
                name="additional_info" UILabel="Notes" mandatory="N" default="NA"
                updatable="Y" viewable="Y" attribute_id="END12" />
        </attributes>
    </editor_tab>
```

I am using DOM parser for xml parsing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What works, what doesn't? Please include the Java code you are having a problem with.

Comment: Hi Tichodroma, I just tried to convert the xml to json object. So that I will take the json object which i want. Finally i'll convert that json object to xml. I ll get the xml but many new unwanted tags have been added. So I dropped that idea.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Have you gotten anything to work so far?

Comment: You xml seams more an xml-fragment. You may use simple regular expression matching.

Comment: @whowantsakookie:I have an xml, in that i just need a particular tag block. how do i accomplish through java? That, is there any way in java to extract the particular tags along with its values from my xml?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with Java's DOM API.

Comment: @whowantsakookie: I tried using DOM parser like below code(the xpath is different. not for the xml above),
    Node result = (Node)xpath.evaluate("//canvas/relType/entity/identity/ConcreteId/@jsonsrc", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
   
 System.out.println(nodeToString(result));

in the nodeToString() method I use xml transformation to get the xml. But it is giving the null result.

Comment: Yes, but *what specifically* have you tried? We need code. We need what you have tried, what's worked, failed, everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlstring)
NodeList editorTab = doc.getElementsByTagName("editor_tab")
Element et = (Element)editorTab.item(0)
```

would be sufficient to get the editor_tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Java's built in Java API. [This tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) helped me a lot when I was learning how to parse XML. I hope it will help you too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(responseXml));
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```

**InputSource** is from **org.xml.sax.InputSource**

more info : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/ParseanXMLstringUsingDOMandaStringReader.htm
   Hope this helps.